# I compiled R from source and it doesn't find certificates

Tags: r, linux, deployment, compilation, certificate

I am deploying multiple R versions on multiple virtual desktops. I've built `3.6.3` and `4.1.2` [R](https://www.r-project.org/) from source on `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`. None of them finds the system-wide `Rprofile.site` file in `/etc/R` or the system certificates in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`. However R (`3.4.4`) installed with APT has no such problems. I used Ansible, but for the sake of this question I reproduced the deployment for one host with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# install build dependecies
(command -v apt && apt-get build-dep r-base) || (command -v dnf && dnf builddep R)


version='4.1.2'
major_version=$(echo "$version" | cut -c 1)

wget "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-$major_version/R-$version.tar.gz"
tar -xzf R-$version.tar.gz
cd R-$version

./configure \
        --prefix=/opt/R/$version \
        --sysconfdir=/etc/R \
        --enable-R-shlib \
        --with-pcre1 \
        --with-blas \
        --with-lapack
make -j 8
make install
```

Note: It should run on most Linux distros with APT or RPM package managers. Increase the `-j` argument of `make`, if you have the enough cores, but no time.

So I defined the installation prefix as `/opt/R/$version` , but I want it read config files from `/etc/R` (defined `--sysconfdir=/etc/R`). However when I open the R interactive shell (`/opt/R/4.1.2/bin/R`) to try install a package:

```
install.packages("remotes")
```

then I will be prompted to choose a R package mirror, but one already defined in `/etc/R/Rprofile.site`:

```
local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "https://cloud.r-project.org"
    options(repos = r)
})
```

I can force the R shell to find the `Rprofile.site` file by defining it with the `R_PROFILE` environment variable.

```
export R_PROFILE=/etc/R/Rprofile.site
/opt/R/4.1.2/bin/R
```

then call `install.packages("remotes")` again in the R shell. Now no mirror selection prompt will be shown, but the following error:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘remotes’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

So it cannot access the repository index (real problem), then concludes that the package ‘remotes’ package is not available for my R version. Which is BS, since it was not able to read the index at the first place. So I tried a simple HTTP call in the same R shell.

```
curlGetHeaders("https://example.com")
```

and got this error:

```
Error in curlGetHeaders("https://example.com") : libcurl error code 77:
        unable to access SSL/TLS CA certificates
```

So it cannot find the CA certificates in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`.

Since the R installed by APT has none of these problems. The compiled R does not search the right places. Even if I omit the `--sysconfdir=/etc/R` build option and copy or symlink the `/etc/R` directory under the prefix, so it will be at `/opt/R/4.1.2/etc`. It will still not find its config files.

The greater problem that I do not even no know how to specify the `/usr/share` so it may find the certificates. The `rsharedir` build options (the `--` also missing in the makefile) will not do, because it should point to `/usr/share/R/` not `/usr/share`, which would be a bad practice anyway.

I also tried all of this it with the `3.6.3` R version and got the same results.

Questions: How can I make the compiled R installations to find the system-wide or any config files and the certificates.

## Update 1

I ran the build script on a Ubuntu server which I do not manage with the same Ansible code. On both of them R successfully finds the certificates. So the problem is not with the build script but the system state.

## Update 2

I created a simple R script (`install-r-package.R`) which install a package:

```
install.packages("renv", repos="https://cran.wu.ac.at/")
```

then I executed it with `Rscript` and traced which file do they open on both the correct and erroneous hosts:

```
 strace -o strace.log -e trace=open,openat,close,read,write,connect,accept ./Rscript install-r-package.R
```

It turned out that on the problematic system R does not even try to open the certificate files.

The relevant trace snippet on the correct system:

```
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("137.208.57.37")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", O_RDONLY) = 6
read(6, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIH"..., 200704) = 200704
read(6, "--\n", 4096)                   = 3
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
```

on the problematic system:

```
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("137.208.57.37")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nss/libsoftokn3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
read(6, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220A\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
close(6)                                = 0
```

In both cases R connects to the mirror (`137.208.57.37`) after that on the correct system it reads the `ca-certificates.crt` certificate file and many other .crt files after that. However the erroneous system jump this step altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

Since both system has the arch and OS. I cross copied the R compiled installations between them. The R which was compiled on the problematic system, but was run on the correct one gave the warnings below after the calling of the `install.packages("renv", repos="https://cran.wu.ac.at/")`

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.wu.ac.at/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/R/4.1.2/lib/R/modules//internet.so':
  libcurl-nss.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2: package ‘remotes’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

If I do the reverse then the installation works.

The `libcurl-nss.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` line gave me the clue that different libcurl4 flavors was used as build dependecies. I checked which dev dependecies were installed on the systems and `libcurl4-nss-dev 7.58.0-2ubuntu3` were installed on the problematic system and `libcurl4-gnutls-dev 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.16` on the correct system.

So I purged `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` from the problematic system:

```
apt purge libcurl4-nss-dev -y
```

and installed libcurl4-gnutls-dev:

```
aptitude install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

I used aptitude, because I had to downgrade libcurl3-gnutls `7.58.0-2ubuntu3.16 (now) -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu3 (bionic)` which is a dependency of `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, then I run a `make clean` in the R-4.1.2 source directory. Finally I re-run the build script from the question, and got a well working R, which can read the certificates, hence can reach the HTTPS using package mirrors.